# Why does this autocommand works on neovim but not on vim?

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, conceal

I have this little augroup that contains a simple autocommand
that hides the `/home/devs/` text on top of nerdtree:

```
augroup HideHOME
  autocmd! FileType nerdtree
  autocmd FileType nerdtree syntax match NERDTreeHideCWD 
        \ #^[</]home[/]devs[/]# conceal
augroup end
```

It works well on my neovim setup.. but not on vim(8.1),
I even tried pasting this into a separate file then source
using `vim -u HideHome.vim` but it still doesn't work..

The weird thing is when I typed it manually on the commandline it works.

`:syntax match NERDTreeHideCWD #^[</]home[/]devs[/]# conceal`

they also have the same `concealcursor` and `conceallevel` values so what might be the problem in vim?

EDIT: Okay I still don't know what's the cause but I'm sourcing this from the system-wide vimrc in /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/vimrc and when I tried from ~/vimrc it works.. If anybody can enlighten me I'll gladly accept it as the answer.

Comment: Okay I still don't know what's the cause but I'm sourcing this from the system-wide vimrc in `/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/vimrc` and when I tried from `~/vimrc` it works.. If anybody can enlighten me I'll gladly accept it as the answer.

Comment: Avoid putting custom code in system-wide vim configs (unless multiuser machine and your intention is to update the config for everyone).

Comment: You're sourcing it from an already initialized instance of vim? It may have a run-once conditional (something like `if <condition> | finish | endif`).  Just a guess since I don't have your system vimrc.